# How to implement reconnection and/or close connection in actioncable JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, electron, actioncable

I have a node application that uses actioncable, the problem is the subscription is closed between 1hour and 2hours from the connection.
I want to handle this by manually closing the connection then reconnect when I didn't receive a msg since some minutes.

The code:

```
cable.subscribe(msgUpdate, {
  connected() {
    console.log("connected");
  },

  disconnected(error) {
    console.log("disconnected", error);
  },

  rejected(error) {
    console.log("rejected", error);
  },

  received(data) {
    if (data?.result?.errors?.length > 0) {
      console.log("error", data?.result?.errors);
      return;
    }
    const msg = data?.result?.data;
    console.log(msg);
  },
```

Link of the implementation:
https://github.com/sorare/actioncable

Thanks!